# pick elements cumulatively from a vector in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, lapply

I'm using the following to cumulatively (i.e., *first pick first 2 elements and each time add 1 more; see output below*) pick elements from vector `mods` below. I wonder if there is a faster or simpler approach to doing this in BASE R?

```
n <- names(mtcars) # BASE R dataset

lapply(seq_along(n)[-1], function(i)n[seq_len(i)]) # any faster or simpler approach here?

[[1]]
[1] "mpg" "cyl"

[[2]]
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp"

[[3]]
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"  

[[4]]
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(c, n, accumulate=TRUE)
```

or, to start with the first two elements:

```
Reduce(c, tail(n,-2), n[1:2], accumulate=TRUE)
```

It is simpler IMHO, but not faster:

```
microbenchmark(
    lapply=lapply(seq_along(n)[-1], function(i)n[seq_len(i)]), 
    Reduce=Reduce(c, n, accumulate=TRUE)
)

Unit: microseconds
   expr  min   lq   mean median   uq    max neval
 lapply 10.2 10.6 22.056   10.8 11.0 1119.8   100
 Reduce 10.1 10.4 10.865   10.6 10.8   17.5   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `rep` and `split`

```
split(n[sequence(seq_along(n))], rep(seq_along(n), seq_along(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/index.html) package and [`window_run`](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/window_run.html) function which does exactly what you asking for. You can also specify number (`k`) of elements you'd like to be returned in each window. You can also specify `lag` and make windows depending on date. Here is example:

```
library(runner)
window_run(names(mtcars))

# [[1]]
# [1] "mpg"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "mpg" "cyl"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"
```

---

In benchmark it's very similar to `Reduce` solution, because of cpp implementation:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  window_run = window_run(names(mtcars)),
      Reduce = Reduce(c, n, accumulate = TRUE),
      lapply = lapply(seq_along(n)[-1], function(i) n[seq_len(i)]),
       times = 1000000L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min     lq     mean median     uq       max neval
#  window_run 10.296 12.782 15.45241 13.543 14.467  98018.87 1e+06
#      Reduce 10.979 13.048 15.80921 13.882 14.847  98881.51 1e+06
#      lapply 11.797 14.540 17.42722 15.518 16.729 116346.98 1e+06
```

For more details checkout [documentation](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/index.html)